# Using filters in header group in react bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, react-bootstrap-table

i'm trying to use filters in react bootstrap table, the filters shows but they are not aligned [you can see it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp3I4.png)

and this is the code i"m using :

```
                <BootstrapTable key={this.props.index}>

                <TableHeaderColumn columnTitle row='0' filter={filterBy} rowSpan='2' dataField='product' headerText='SSS' isKey>id</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn row='0' colSpan='2' headerAlign= 'center'>Product</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn row='1' filter={filterBy} dataField='prodDesc'>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn row='1' filter={filterBy} dataField='standardCost'>Price</TableHeaderColumn>

                </BootstrapTable>
```

is there any way to make the filters on the same level ?

Answer (score 1):

You have nested headings, that's why I suggest you to align the titles vertically at the bottom of the row.

Please try to add

```
.react-bs-table th {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

and have in mind, that maybe you have to add `!important` to apply it.